# Why do these C struct definitions give warnings and errors?

Tags: c, gcc, struct

Why do these two struct definitions compile fine:

```
struct foo {
    int a;
} __attribute__((packed));

typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    int a;
} bar;
```

While this one gives a warning:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
} baz __attribute__((packed));


warning: ‘packed’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
```

And this one gives an error and a warning:

```
typedef struct qux __attribute__((packed)) {
    int a;
} qux;

error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
```

As a novice C programmer, the fact that the last two definitions don't work seems like a fairly arbitrary choice on the parts of the language designers/compiler writers. Is there a reason for this? I'm using gcc 4.7.3.

Comment: Not an answer, I know, but if you're a C novice, you probably shouldn't be trying to pack structures in the first place.  For one thing, this isn't standard C but a gcc extension.

Comment: With a structure containing a single `int` (or any single member of any type), there is nothing to pack anyway; the size of the packed and the unpacked structure will be the same.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was hoping the use of foo, bar, baz, etc. would illustrate that this code is clearly an example, not the actual code I'm working with.

Answer (score 7):

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    int a;
} bar;
```

vs

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
} baz __attribute__((packed));
```

In the first you said "consider this anonymous structure, with the attribute packed, that has a member a. then create an alias for this structure, and name that 'bar'". The normal syntax for describing a struct without doing it anonymously and having to typedef it is

```
struct bar { int a; };
```

in the second declaration you said "consider this anonymous structure, that has a member a. then create an alias for this structure, and name that 'baz who is packed'".

It doesn't work because you're trying to apply the attribute to the alias in a typedef, not to the structure definition.

```
typedef <entity> <alias>;
```

I would advise putting on a hit on whomever suggested you use the "typedef" syntax for describing structs :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it works in the first two instances is because `__attribute__((packed))` can only be applied to a `struct`, `union` or `enum`.  In the first example, you're declaring a `struct` called `foo`, in the second you are declaring a `struct` called `bar`.  In this second example, `typedef` converts a declaration of a variable into a declaration of a type.

Your third example is declaring a variable called `baz` and trying to declare it as packed.  Since packing info is attached to the type, not an instance, this makes no sense, and the compiler ignores it.

Here are [details on how attributes work in gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html).

You really shouldn't be even using packed unless you know exactly what you are doing.  For one thing, `__attribute__` is not standard C.  If is a `gcc` extension and so won't work with any other compiler.

For another, there are very few situations where it is actually needed.  In your code above, for instance, it is a no-op even in the first two instances as packing removes space between members, and you've only got one member in each `struct`.  The reason that packing structures isn't the default is because common datatypes just work better when aligned on a certain boundary.  For instance, access to an `int` will perform better if aligned on a memory location that is a multiple of four.    See [the wiki entry on data structure alignment for more information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `__attribute__((packed))` applies to *struct*.

In

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
} baz __attribute__((packed));
```

*typedef* associates *baz* with the struct - the attributes comes after, and applies to nothing - gcc ignores it. To fix this, allow *typedef* to associate the whole *struct* declaration, including the *attribute*, by placing *baz* after the attribute:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
} __attribute__((packed)) baz;
```

In the 2nd example, the *struct* declaration is wrong

```
struct qux __attribute__((packed)) {
    int a;
}
```

as *quz* should appear after the attribute:

```
struct __attribute__((packed)) qux {
    int a;
}
```

It is usually better to let the compiler optimizes the structure and align the inner elements in memory in a way the CPU processes them more efficiently.

Packing a structure, however, may be important at times when building a data structure that *has to* be packed, in order to cope, for instance, with a driver demands.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather odd question because it's all very well explained in the manual. However to there isn't anything arbitrary about it, you're just not exploring the complete use of this built-in keyword:

`__attribute__(())` is a general purpose gcc extension. There are function attributes, type attributes and variable attributes.

Where you place the word `__attribute__` determines what it applies to. You could potentially have several `__attribute__`s in a given declaration so it's not arbitrary to make some of it syntactically unacceptable for easier internal parsing.